# Android : Force the use of the dot instead of the comma with decimal EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, locale

How can I force the use of the dot instead of the comma with decimal EditTexts?

String.replace(",", ".") is not a valid solution for me.

I though to set the US Locale programmatically, but it changed the language too.

Is there a way to change the Locale without changing the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the following for different locales

```
private void localeDecimalInput(final EditText editText){

    DecimalFormat decFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=decFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    final String defaultSeperator=Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator());

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(editable.toString().contains(defaultSeperator))
                editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
            else
                editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + defaultSeperator));
        }


});
}
```

or **solution 2** 
use an `EditText` with `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` and `android:digits="0123456789.,"`.

Then add a `TextChangedListener` to the `EditText` with the following `afterTextChanged`:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    double doubleValue = 0;
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.'));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Error
        }
    }
    //Do something with doubleValue
}
```